# How to rotate image used as list type in unordered list

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

I am able to rotate image with below CSS.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="box-menu">
<img src="someurl" class="rotate-img">
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.box-menu:hover >.binja-blade{
-webkit-animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite spin;
   -moz-animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite spin;
    -ms-animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite spin;
     -o-animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite spin;
        animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite spin;
}
```

But if I use that image as list type in `li` then how I can rotate that image when we hover that particular `li` ?.

```
<ul class="box-menu" style="list-style-image:url('someURL');">
<li>Mumbai</li>
<li>Hyderabad</li>
<li>Pune</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rotate background-image nor bullets, but pseudo-element , yes .
Idea is :

```
 li {
list-style-type:none;
padding-left:20px;
}
li:before {
content:url(yourImage.png);
margin-left:-20px;
display:inline-block;
}
li:hover:before {
transform:rotate(360000deg);
transition:300s;/* tune this */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LHsjr/)**

Comment: you can spare an animation rule :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is even possible. You can set the image, but don't see how you would add css to that image.

You might change the image via CSS on hover and use an animated instead of the static one.

Here is a link to where you can easelly generate rotating anemated gifs: http://www.ajaxload.info/

Hope this helps

Comment: Problem is rotating ajax loader image will never be stopped. And I want to rotate only on hover and also I have my image so this link didn't help me. But anyway thanks.

Comment: Then, on mouseout set the non-rotating image again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this so you can get your answer..i was searching and i found this..hope it will help ful..
[How to rotate li:before independently of the li?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570271/how-to-rotate-libefore-independently-of-the-li)